# The underlying provider failed on open

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I know this question has been asked a few times already, but I tried all the solutions I found on stackoverflow and everywhere else and nothing worked, so I'm asking again I'm sorry

I used to connect to a remote database on a server, but to test some things I had to backup this database and restore it locally. The thing is, when I try to replace the server name by ".\SQLEXPRESS" in the connection strings, everytime I try to use the database (juste display datas as exemple), I got the error you can see in the title.

I already tried to Allow remote connections in my local DTC, I tried to open the connection, tried the sp_users command, nothing worked

Here is my connection string :

```
    <add name="HDPreDiagEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HDPreDiag.csdl|res://*/HDPreDiag.ssdl|res://*/HDPreDiag.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=HDPreDiag;persist security info=True;user id=id;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Thanks guys for your time and help

Comment: Create a blank notepad and rename it to "X.UDL" Double click open it, under connections tab choose the server name/enter the name use the correct credentials and DB OK to save it.

Now open the file in Notepad and check, compare the connection string properties with this.

Comment: on my win10 it says fail to open X.UDL, any ideas?

Comment: Well I tried the UDL stuff, and when I try to choose the DB, it says "impossible to extract catalog informations"...

Comment: I tried with windows security NT, copied the connection string and it works just fine now, thank you a lot !

Comment: I still don't know what the problem was though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I tried to create a .UDL file, and when I tried to connect with SQL id, it didn't work. I just tried to connect with Windows NT security, opened the .UDL with notepad and copied the connection string in my App.config and it works fine now.

If anyone know why I couldn't connect with my DB ids, I'd be glad to hear (knowing that they exist...)